# Error "no function with name [GETDATAACCESSFACTORY]" starting Mango Blog

Tags: coldfusion, railo

```
Error: onApplicationStart: component [org.mangoblog.Mango] has no function with name [GETDATAACCESSFACTORY]
```

I got this error once I've installed MangoBlog. I've already checked there is "GETDATAACCESSFACTORY" function in components/mango.cfc file.

PS: I've installed it on Railo.

Comment: Do you have the Mango application located in web-root?

Comment: yap, sure. it's located under ../wwww/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I helped ppshein on the Mango Blog forums, where he also posted this issue. It turns out that all he had to do was restart his CFML App Server (Railo).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a plug-in you should have installed but don't for some reason. I'd compare a fresh downloaded version with what's on the webroot. Beyond Compare will do it for you in a blink

Comment: Sorry, it's because of Application variable storing. It's fine after restarting server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error, and I am on a shared host so I can't restart Railo without emailing my host. But I DO have access to the Railo administrator, and I found that clearing the caches did the trick for me. In Railo Admin go to Settings->Performance/Caching and click all the Clear **_** Cache buttons. I am not sure which you need to clear...you may be fine just clearing Component cache. I just cleared them all and